# Difference between do_action_ref_array() and do_action()

Tags: actions

I am having trouble wrapping my head around these two functions. I understand `do_action()` but I don't see clearly when [`do_action_ref_array()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/do_action_ref_array) would be useful. Couldn't we pass an array to `do_action()` as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- If you pass an array to `do_action_ref_array()`, each element’s value of that array will be passed as a separate parameter to the callback. The keys are lost.
- If you pass an array to `do_action()`, the complete array will be passed as one single parameter to the callback. The keys stay intact.

Let’s look at the differences between `do_action()` and `do_action_ref_array()` in a simple plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer',             'action_diff_test' );
add_action( 'diff_action',           'diff_test_callback', 10, 999 );
add_action( 'diff_action_ref_array', 'diff_test_callback', 10, 999 );

/**
 * call test actions
 */
function action_diff_test()
{
    $args = array (
        'foo'   => 'bar',
        'hello' => 'world',
        0       => 123
    );

    do_action(           'diff_action',           $args );
    do_action_ref_array( 'diff_action_ref_array', $args );
}
/**
 * callback for test actions
 */
function diff_test_callback()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    print current_filter() . ', ' . func_num_args() . ' arguments';
    ?>
    <pre><?php
    print htmlspecialchars(
        print_r( $args, TRUE ),
        ENT_QUOTES,
        'utf-8',
        FALSE
    );
    ?></pre>
    <?php
}
```

Result:

```
diff_action, 1 arguments 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
            [hello] => world
            [0] => 123
        )

)

diff_action_ref_array, 3 arguments 
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => world
    [2] => 123
)
```

`do_action_ref_array()` was [introduced 2006](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/3125) to handle parameters [passed by reference](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html) better in PHP 4. A [review of the function 2011](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16661) was closed as *wontfix*. But the conclusion was not to use for new functions in WordPress anymore, because in PHP 5 you can do that with `do_action()` too. The problem from 2006 is not a problem nowadays.

Do not use `do_action_ref_array()` in your custom hooks, but learn how to read it.

Comment: Hi fuxia! I'm not understanding why you used 999 as the number of arguments. I was expecting that to be `add_action('a', 'c', 999, 1);` and `add_action('b', 'c', 999, 3);`

Comment: @brasofilo That's because you don't always know how big the incoming array is.

Comment: I see now, makes perfect sense. Thanks for the feedback