# Exclude Users of a Certain Role in the Users Page

Tags: wp-user-query

```
class MyPlugin {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'do_member_filter'));
    }

    public function do_member_filter() {
        $users = new WP_User_Query( array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => "{$GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix}capabilities",
                    'value'   => 'abcrole',
                    'compare' => '!='
                )
            )
        ));


        do_action_ref_array('pre_user_query', $users);
    }
}
```

Comment: For later readers: [Do not use `do_action_ref_array()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90640/difference-between-do-action-ref-array-and-do-action) anymore. Core stopped using it as well as there's no reason in PHP5.

Answer (score 1):

### How to use the class methods in the callback

The `$query` object inside `pre_user_query` is a fully qualified core `object`, so you can use `$query->set( 'key', 'value' );` as well as `$query->get( 'key' );`.

If you got the problem that this might interfere with other callbacks, then simply add `remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );` to your callback, so it removes itself during the first call.

### Another way to go

You can as well use those arguments directly when instantiating the class:

```
$users = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'    => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => "{$GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix}capabilities",
            'value'   => 'abcrole',
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => "{$GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix}capabilities",
            'value'   => 'ab',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    )
) );
```

#### Benefits

This example shows how you can exclude users by a `capability` or `role` that matches exactly or is only named `LIKE` the role you'd like to exclude. This comes handy when you for example prefix some of your roles or capabilities and then want to mass-exclude them.

You can as well just use the same in the callback. Pay attention that you use an `array( array() )` for your meta query.

Comment: thank you! I tried both solution but it doesn't work for me. The first sulotion which is the $query->set() doesn't work as expected and then the second one resulted to a "Problem loading page". Infinite loop maybe going on on the second solution I guess. I am firing this one on the pre_user_query action.

Comment: @Godwinh Then please update your question and show us **all** of your surrounding code.

Comment: It is now updated with 1st and 2nd solution

Comment: I have edited my code above again but still doesn't work. I have checked if there are other callbacks attached to the hook but there isn't any.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] );` and show the `meta_query` part after you used the code from my answer. You could as well dump inside the `posts_clauses` filter and show us the dump.